# Command for adding a default constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, default-constraint

There appears to be at least two ways to add a default constraint using straight T-SQL. Am I correct that the only difference between the two below is that the second method specifically creates a name for the constraint, and the first method has one generated by SQL Server?

```
ALTER TABLE [Common].[PropertySetting] ADD DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active];
ALTER TABLE [Common].[PropertySetting] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_PropertySetting_Active) DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active];
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Pretty much, yes for an `ALTER TABLE`

You can add a columnn with default in one step for `CREATE` or `ALTER` too.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD bar varchar(100) CONSTRAINT DF_Foo_Bar DEFAULT ('bicycle');

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD bar varchar(100) DEFAULT ('bicycle');
```

As you noted, the system generates a name if one is not supplied. [`CONSTRAINT constraint_name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx) is optional says MSDN. The same applies to any [column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186712.aspx) or [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) CONSTRAINT

---

If the column was already created, and you only want to add a (named) `DEFAULT` constraint, then use:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Foo_Bar DEFAULT 'bicycle' FOR FieldName;
```

To have the system generate the `DEFAULT` constraint name (which will be of the form `DF_{TableName}_{Column}_{8RandomChars}`, e.g. `DF_TableName_FieldName_12345678`) then omit the `CONSTRAINT <name>` part, like so:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD DEFAULT 'bicycle' FOR FieldName;
```

Comment: Can I use a generated name instead of `DF_Foo_Bar`, even if the column already exists?

Comment: @slartidan Yes, use the syntax `ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName ADD DEFAULT(SYSUTCDATETIME()) FOR Created;` to create a system-named constraint object. Note that the "`CONSTRAINT`" keyword must be omitted (which is confusing).